# How to set a custom column name in reactJS?

Tags: c#, reactjs

I was getting the column names from database in my react JS app, but now i want to set custom names for my columns. How do I achieve that?

I tried using Column Title but i am getting an error saying Identifier expected. I am using the data from my web API which generates 4 columns. I am getting my data for the `columns={columns}` by mapping all the data in my database, which is the first part of my code that I shared.[Here is what my column names look like initially.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qq1j.jpg), which are exactly like my database table.[SQL database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlLzo.jpg)

```
    let columns = _.map(_.keys(this.state.items[0]), i => {
      return {
        title: i,
        dataIndex: i,
        key: i
      } 
    })

    return (

       <div>
       <Table pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}      
       bordered={true} dataSource={this.state.items} columns={columns}  
        {/* i tried column title = "some name", but its not working */}
       />
       </div>
    );
  }
```

I was getting the names of columns exactly as they were declared in database(is that a bad practice?). I am a beginner in ReactJS.

Comment: Where is the Table component coming from? You have already passed your predefined columns in your columns attribute `columns={columns}` so maybe that is causing the issue of not letting you overwrite. It depends on how the <Table> componenent is configured.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! Edit your question and include all the required information for a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.